# ¿cómo puedo sumar todas las letras de un vector?

Tags: java

Buenas, estoy en primer semestre y tengo que crear un programa que permita almacenar N objetos tipo estudiante en un vector (`nombre`, `cédula`, `nota`) y no se cómo sumar las letras de los nombres ayuda.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ProyectoColegio {


public static void main(String[] args) {
 // Declaramos
    Notas e[]=new Notas[3];
    String n,c;
    float v;
    float Notamayor;


    for (int k=0;k<e.length;k++)
    {
    n=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el nombre");
    c=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la cedula");
    v=Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la nota"));

    // Creamos el objeto
    e[k]=new Notas (n,c,v);
    }
    for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e[k].getNombre() + " Su nota es " + e[k].pago());
    }
}
public static void mostrar(Notas e[])
{
    String salida="";
    for(int k=0;k<e.length;k++)
    {
        salida=salida+e[k].mostrardatos()+""+e[k].pago()+"\n";
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"NOMBRE CEDULA NOTAS\n"+salida);
}

 public static void buscar(Notas e[], String c)
{
    int pos=-1;
    for(int k=0;k<e.length;k++)
    {
        if(e[k].getCedula().equals(c))
        {
        pos=k;  
        }
    }
    if(pos==-1)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "la cedula no se encuentra");
    }
    else
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "la informacion correspondiente es\n"+e[pos].mostrardatos());   
    }
    }
    public static void notamayor(Notas e[], float v)
    {
    if (Notamayor>Notamayor){
        Notamayor=Notamayor;
        estudiantemayor =i;
    }

     }

    }


public class Notas{
//Atributos
String nombre;
String cedula;
float vh;
float Notamayor;

//Metodos :

// Constructor
public Notas (String nombre, String cedula, float vh)
{
    this.nombre=nombre;
    this.cedula=cedula;
    this.vh=vh;
    this.Notamayor=Notamayor;

}

// Asignar un valor al atributo nombre y obtener nombre
public void setNombre(String n)
{
    nombre=n;
}
public String getNombre()
{
    return(nombre);
}
    // Asignar un valor al atributo cedula y obtener cedula
public void setCedula(String c)
{
    cedula=c;
}
public String getCedula()
{
    return(cedula);
}
    // Asignar un valor al atributo vh y obtener vh
public void setVh(float v)
{
    vh=v;
}
public float getVh()
{
    return(vh);
}
// Calcular el pago
public float pago()
{
    return(vh);
}
//metodo para mostrar los datos
public String mostrardatos()
{
    String datos=nombre + " "+cedula+" "+vh+ " ";
    return(datos);
}
public void setNotamayor(float Notamayor)
{
    Notamayor=Notamayor;
}
public float getNotamayor()
{
    return (Notamayor);
}

}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el código que has intentado o el que tienes hasta ahora mostrando donde te has atascado? Muchas gracias!

Comment: sería conveniente poner solo el código relevante

Comment: Está excelente que hayas compartido lo que has hecho hasta ahora. Ahora, lo que falta es que nos ayudes a entender cuales porciones del código son las que se relacionan a la pregunta, y donde en particular necesitas ayuda. Por ahora, es difícil entender cuales partes del código son las importantes y relevantes para tu pregunta.

Comment: a que te refieres con esto... " sumar las letras de los nombres."?

Comment: Por lo que entendí, quieres saber cuantas letras tiene el nombre no? si es así, solo usa la propiedad length

Answer (score 1):

si lo que buscas es un resultado como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es tan sencillo como esto:

```
 int total=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        total += e[i].letrasnum();
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"el total de las letras de los nombre es: "+ total);
```

donde **letrasnum()** está en la clase Notas así:

```
public int letrasnum(){
    return (nombre.length());
}
```

si no es lo que buscas, lo siento, entonces no entendí tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Dado que ya tienes los getters y setter de tu objeto Cedula y los dos tienen un tamaño especifico solo tienes que llamarlos mediante la propiedad de lenght 
en tu misma funcion:

```
public static void mostrar(Notas e[])
{
    String salida="";
    for(int k=0;k<e.length;k++)
    {
        Notas notas = e.[k];
        System.out.println("El nombre contiene :" + notas.getNombre().length() + " letras");
        salida=salida+e[k].mostrardatos()+""+e[k].pago()+"\n";
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"NOMBRE CEDULA NOTAS\n"+salida);
}
```

Y asi susesivamente para la cedula y demas. Espero que te sirva.